# Where is server.conf file kept openCPU ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, opencpu

Sorry if this is answered elsewhere, or requires a trick.

I have installed openCPU on an ubuntu xenial-16.04 instance. I'd like to lengthen the `timelimit.post` value as instructed in the `/etc/opencpu/server.conf` file. Trouble is I can't find it.

`ubuntu@ip-x-x-x-x:/usr/lib/opencpu$ ls -a
.  ..  library  rapache  scripts`

Comment: What file listing do you get when you run `ls -la /etc/opencpu/`

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Sep  7 05:08 .`
`drwxr-xr-x 109 root root 4096 Sep 12 08:06 ..`
`-rw-r--r--   1 root root  246 Dec 15  2017 Renviron`
`-rw-r--r--   1 root root  128 Jun 28  2017 Rprofile`
`-rw-r--r--   1 root root   24 Dec 15  2017 secret.conf`
`-rw-r--r--   1 root root  656 Aug 21 21:45 server.conf`
`drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Sep  7 05:08 server.conf.d`

Comment: This was helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11286/what-do-the-abbreviations-etc-and-usr-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe please check again to see if you don't find `/etc/opencpu/server.conf` in the expected directory - i.e. because, as above in your output of `ls -la /etc/opencpu/`, the `server.conf` file is listed being there. Note though the owner is root so take that into account when you try to open+edit the file.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. :-)  Please mark this as the accepted answer if it solved your problem.  Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers